# Master2 and Master3 in notReady states. Seems related to user config in kubelet.conf

Tags: kubernetes

After applying certificates renewal, I have the following issue. Only one master is ready

```
root@cl9master1:~# kubectl get nodes | grep master
cl9master1    Ready      master   401d   v1.15.0
cl9master2    NotReady   master   401d   v1.15.0
cl9master3    NotReady   master   401d   v1.15.0
```

The logs returned by "journalctl -xeu kubelet" :

```
août 07 09:52:15 cl9master2 kubelet[1101]: E0807 09:52:15.043958    1101 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: 
Failed to list *v1beta1.CSIDrriver: csidrivers.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "default-auth" cannot list ressource "csidrivers" in API group "storage.k8s.io" 
at the cluster scope

août 07 09:52:15 cl9master2 kubelet[1101]: E0807 09:52:15.088813    1101 kubelet.go:2248] node "cl9master2" not found
août 07 09:52:15 cl9master2 kubelet[1101]: E0807 09:52:15.189120    1101 kubelet.go:2248] node "cl9master2" not found
août 07 09:52:15 cl9master2 kubelet[1101]: E0807 09:52:15.236669    1101 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:444: 
Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "default-auth" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
août 07 09:52:15 cl9master2 kubelet[1101]: E0807 09:52:15.289371    1101 kubelet.go:2248] node "cl9master2" not found
août 07 09:52:15 cl9master2 kubelet[1101]: E0807 09:52:15.389664    1101 kubelet.go:2248] node "cl9master2" not found
```

Looking at the kubectl.conf, there are differences between master1 and master2/3

For master1:

```
root@cl9master1:~# cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0t...LQo=
    server: https://10.35.104.69:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: system:node:cl9master1
  name: system:node:cl9master1@kubernetes
current-context: system:node:cl9master1@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: system:node:cl9master1
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
    client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
```

For master2

```
root@cl9master2:~# cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0t...LQo=
    server: https://10.35.104.75:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: default-auth
  name: default-auth@kubernetes
current-context: default-auth@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-auth
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
    client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
```

What can I check and how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Node users must be in system:nodes (if it is worker node or system:master if it is master node) group, it looks like master2 use default-auth which is out of system:nodes group and doesn't have correct permission to list the services. If your node is outside of system:nodes group then you need to have proper RBAC set for the user default-auth to make it work.

You can fix this is in 2 ways:

1. Change the master2 user group into system:nodes (like user: system:node:cl9master2) note: certificates also need to created with proper Oranisation & CN value
2. or Create a proper RBAC for default-auth user.

Please refer docs page [enter link description here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/node/)

Thanks,
Kiruba

Comment: My mistake comes probably from the fact that I ran this command on master1:
# kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --client-name system:node:cl9master1 --org system:nodes > /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf

While I ran this one on master2:
# kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --client-name default-auth --org system:nodes > /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf

I should probably rerun the command on master2 with system:node:cl9master2 instead of default-auth

Comment: I confirm : I solved the issue by rerunning the following command on master2 and master3 : # kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --client-name system:node:cl9masterX --org system:nodes > /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf